# Unable to find element using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to click on a button, but selenium can't find the element.

[image]

I'm using the xpath:

```
//button[@title="Monitor Chart(Ctrl+Alt+G)"]
```

but selenium can't locate. I can find the xpath from Chrome manualy using the find(Ctrl+F) tool, as we can see in the image.

Here is my code and error. The xpath does't have an ID.

Code Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: try copying the full x path from the inspect tab and using that as test_1

Answer (score 2):

To click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.eui-btn.eui-btn-default.eui-btn-normal[title^='Monitor Chart']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='eui-btn eui-btn-default eui-btn-normal' and starts-with(@title, 'Monitor Chart')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figure it out the issue. the button was inside an iframe. But you solution gave me an idea to another issues that I was having. Instead of use timesleep function, I'm gonna use your solution with WebdriverWait

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

hiding_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[title ='Monitor Chart(Ctrl+Alt+G)']")))
hiding_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all. But I figure it out the issue. The button was inside an iFrame. So I hadd to switch to the iFrame first.

Code used:

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_id('Access_Performance_Monitor')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```